# How to change font scale from Terminal

Tags: terminal, fonts, screen-resolution

I know these two commands to change density and resolution via Terminal:

```
wm density <dpi>
wm size <resolution>
```

But how do I change the scale of system-wide font via Terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer from StackOverflow ([How to change font size by adb command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916983)) provides a solution. The command used to set the font size is:

```
adb shell settings put system font_scale {float_representing_the_scale}
```

or if you are using a terminal emulator in Android

```
settings put system font_scale {float_representing_the_scale}
```

Examples:

```
settings put system font_scale 0.5f
settings put system font_scale 1.2f
```

I tested it using Android 6.0 with root access (I was getting an error when using the command without root). I had to restart the phone for the setting to take effect.